# $f(0)=0,\;\;f(x)=e^{-2/x}\sin\left(e^{1/x}\right)$, is $f$ bounded variation on [0,1]?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, bounded-variation

Let $$f(0)=0,\;\;f(x)=e^{-2/x}\sin\left(e^{1/x}\right),$$ is $f$ bounded variation on $[0,1]$?

Here is my thinking:

Since $f$ is  differentiable on $(0,1]$ and continuous on $[0,1]$

If $f^\prime$ is bounded, we can use mean value theorem to prove it.

Comment: If it helps, let $y=e^{-1/x}$ to transform the function to $g(y)=y^2\sin(1/y)$ on the interval $[0,1/e]$, which is of bounded variation by essentially what you said using the mean value theorem.

Comment: @Alex Is it so obvious that if $g$ has bounded variation then $f$ has bounded variation? I mean, more obvious than the direct approach the OP is advocating?

Answer (score 1):

That is a good approach.

Because $\lim\limits_{x\to 0+} f'(x)$ exists, $f$ is in fact in $C^1[0,1]$, hence absolutely continuous by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.  Absolute continuity implies bounded variation.